# Node: Error in installing npm package

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install node.js package with npm but it's giving me that error.

```
Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\Zain\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: what is the version of node?

Comment: did you install this with the normal nodejs.org windows installer?

Comment: When do you get this error? Please edit your post to show the relevant console log including your initial `npm install ...` command

Comment: I'm new to Node.js. I am trying to install socket.io with npm install socket.io and just getting that error back :-(

Comment: What is the output of `npm -v`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had the same problem today from a clean install as yours.
Solved manually creating the

> C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm

directory.

Hope it helps

Comment: Great thanks user211789. I've done it before your answer by running this npm install -g socket.io.